# Is it possible to read Registry key values from java Web from client machine?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, seam

I want to read specific key values from Windows Registry machine from the web server. I'm using `jsf` and `seam`. I just wanted to check if there is a certain application that was already installed on the client machine and i want to check it from the server side code.

Is this possible?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Try Winpack http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/#registry_access

Comment: Thanks. ill check on this one.

Comment: It's unlikely this will work out. It's a massive security risk and I'll be shocked if a web app can query a client's registry. If you can pull it off, please update us here

Comment: I'll update this when i pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing registry you need to use [Java Native Access (JNA)](http://jna.java.net/)  registry library.

For reading client registry I think you need to use Applet and provide appropriate security permissions

Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: I'm using jna library btw, but it cant read registry values from the client machine from the server code. I can only read from my local machine though.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, you need to put the code which read registry in Applet so that it reads from client machine. Right now it reads from your server registry.